# After setting classpath and path using batch file, still throws errors "Can not find or load main class"

Tags: java, batch-file, javac

Ever since I moved the location of the file, the batch file doesn't seem to *want* to find the class path. I've tried `set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin";` and `set classpath="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\lib"`.

Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
color 3
title Run Java File

set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin";
set classpath="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\lib";

cd C:\Users\user\Documents\Java Test Files\Matthew C\src\calculator

javac Math.java
java Math

pause
```

and the calculator.java file is just a simple "Hello World" type program - which works within a built-in compiler that I use - that is Eclipse.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? I've tried searching multiple answers in and out of Stackoverflow, and none of them seemed to have worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: what's is the error message when you run the bat file,exactly?

Comment: If your app uses built-in classes only, it should work without setting `classpath`. Remove setting `classpath` environment variable. To run `javac` and `java`, the path to JDK `bin` needs to be in `PATH` - you added it. So it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to try...

1. Try running those commands on command prompt and make sure they work.
2. Try double-quoting your path to the app (it has spaces in it).
3. Set JDK path once for the entire system ([like specified here](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java))